# Difference between "vue create NewProjectsName" and "vue init webpack NewProjectsName"?

Tags: vue.js

What is the difference between `vue create NewProjectsName` and `vue init webpack NewProjectsName` commands in vue cli.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With the `vue create NewProjectName` you have more possibilites for configuring the new project you are creating, it let's you decide whether to use the standard options or manually pick what you want (e.g. Babel, TypeScript, PWA support, etc.) - as well as some other options.

`vue init webpack` is a rather simple, only asks some metadata for the project, if you want to use vue-router, ESLint and unit/e2e tests.

Hope this clears up your question.

Comment: Using `vue init webpack projectname` (using npm) shows many vulnerabilities. But `vue create projectname` (using yarn) is direct and simpler and shows no vulnerabilities. Why does this happen?

Comment: also if you are tying to create a project on a vm or on a smb drive
init will work
create not